# Transfer httpenpoinds metrics using http module-metricbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, yaml, kibana, httpmodule, metricbeat

In order to ship the metrics endpoints (/metric) of my spring-boot  app ,I used  http module in metricbeat , I'm following  the official doc in elastic.io website to install and configure metricbeat, but unfrontenly, the transport of metrics was incorrect although the connection had been established. 
.I changed fields.yml file to create a specific template for http module only

fields.yml

```
- key: http
  title: "HTTP"
  description: >
    HTTP module
  release: beta
  settings: ["ssl"]
  fields:
    - name: http
      type: group
      description: >
      fields:
        - name: request
          type: group
          description: >
              HTTP request information
          fields:
            - name: header
              type: object
              description: >
                The HTTP headers sent
            - name: method
              type: keyword
              description: >
                The HTTP method used
            - name: body
              type: keyword
              description: >
                The HTTP payload sent
        - name: response
          type: group
          description: >
              HTTP response information
          fields:
            - name: header
              type: object
              description: >
                The HTTP headers received
            - name: code
              type: keyword
              description: >
                The HTTP status code
              example: 404
            - name: phrase
              type: keyword
              example: Not found
              description: >
                The HTTP status phrase
            - name: body
              type: keyword
              description: >
                The HTTP payload received
        - name: json
          type: group
          description: >
            json metricset
          release: beta
          fields:

        - name: server
          type: group
          description: >
            server
          release: experimental
          fields:
```

metricbeat.yml

```
    metricbeat.config.modules:
      # Glob pattern for configuration loading
      path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
      # Set to true to enable config reloading
      reload.enabled: false
metricbeat.modules:

    #------------------------------- HTTP Module -------------------------------
    - module: http
      metricsets: ["json"]
      period: 10s
      hosts: ["http://localhost:8080/metrics"]
      namespace: "test_metrics"
      method: "GET" 
      enabled: true
      setup.template.overwrite: true
      output.elasticsearch:
         hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
```

My app metrics display:(**http://localhost:8080/metrics**)

```
    {
  "mem": 199405,
  "mem.free": 74297,
  "processors": 4,
  "instance.uptime": 45240231,
  "uptime": 45254636,
  "systemload.average": -1,
  "heap.committed": 154624,
  "heap.init": 131072,
  "heap.used": 80326,
  "heap": 1842688,
  "nonheap.committed": 45888,
  "nonheap.init": 2496,
  "nonheap.used": 44781,
  "nonheap": 0,
  "threads.peak": 31,
  "threads.daemon": 25,
  "threads.totalStarted": 35,
  "threads": 27,
  "classes": 6659,
  "classes.loaded": 6659,
  "classes.unloaded": 0,
  "gc.ps_scavenge.count": 24,
  "gc.ps_scavenge.time": 999,
  "gc.ps_marksweep.count": 1,
  "gc.ps_marksweep.time": 71,
  "httpsessions.max": -1,
  "httpsessions.active": 0,
  "gauge.response.metrics": 20,
  "gauge.response.unmapped": 6005,
  "gauge.response.login": 1,
  "gauge.response.star-star.favicon.ico": 1878,
  "counter.status.200.star-star.favicon.ico": 1,
  "counter.status.200.metrics": 30,
  "counter.status.302.unmapped": 3,
  "counter.status.200.login": 2
}
```

Previously,  I used **httpbeat** and  everything was great,the name  of fields  in elasticsearch index are  compatible ... , since  I've  moved  to use  http module everything  had been changed ,I'm using  it  to get a  predefined  dashboards  in kibana .

Any help please ?

Comment: add the error logs too